# How to check if the footnote mark appears on the same page of the footonote text?

Tags: footnotes, write

For my typesetting purposes I need to check if the "footnote tag" appears in the same page of (the beginning of) the "footnote text". Sometimes indeed, it happens that, e.g., I have the footnote tag in a page and the footnote text in the next page.

Currently I do this check visually... and this is very boring and error prone.

I figured out to (temporarily) redefine the `\footnote` command to make it print the "tag page" and the "text page" in the `.aux` file that I would parse with an elisp script but, honestly I don't have any idea how to do that (I mean the LaTeX part of the trick).

To better exlain my idea, I'd like to have in the `.aux` file a string like this:

```
"Foonote1: footnotemarkePage=X, footnotetextPage=Y"
```

Could anyone help me?

Is there a better solution to do that?

I'm not able to provide a MWE but I hope this can help:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

I need to print this footnote mark.\footnote{Footnote text.} page 
and the related footnote text page in the ``.aux'' file.

\end{document}
```

Here a screenshot of a real case.

[image]

**Note.** I'm not asking a solution to solve the problem but to "detect" it.

**Note added.** Sometimes the footnote text splits into two (or more) pages. It would be helpful a trick to detect this with an automatic solution.

**Work in progress:**

Using an [egreg solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365954/33634) related to a similar issue  I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\NR@setref}[1]{%
    \ref@page@write{#1}%
    \begingroup\@safe@activestrue\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\NR@@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ref@page@write}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ref@page{#1}{\thepage}}%
}
\newcommand{\ref@page}[2]{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{MyFootnote}

\let\MyOldFootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\stepcounter{MyFootnote}\label{FOOTNOTE\arabic{MyFootnote}}\MyOldFootnote{\ref{FOOTNOTE\arabic{MyFootnote}}#1}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}

\section{Section}

I need to print this footnote mark.\footnote{Footnote text.} page and the related footnote text page in the ``.aux'' file.

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

I need to print this footnote mark.\footnote{Footnote text.} page and the related footnote text page in the ``.aux'' file.

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

I need to print this footnote tag.\footnote{Footnote text.} page and the related footnote text page in the ``.aux'' file.

\end{document}
```

Now in the `.aux` file I get:

```
\newlabel{FOOTNOTE1}{{5}{1}{Section}{section.5}{}}
\ref@page{FOOTNOTE1}{1}
\newlabel{FOOTNOTE2}{{5}{2}{Section}{section.5}{}}
\ref@page{FOOTNOTE2}{2}
\newlabel{FOOTNOTE3}{{5}{3}{Section}{section.5}{}}
\ref@page{FOOTNOTE3}{3}
```

So I can compare the page the label is referred to (and where the footenotemark appears) with the page on which the footnotetext appears. The only problem with this solution is that it adds an extra string at the beginning of the foootnote text.

In the case of the screenshot I have:

```
\newlabel{FOOTNOTE11}{{4.2.3}{29}{xxxxxxxxxx}{equation.4.25}{}}
\ref@page{FOOTNOTE11}{31}
```

where "29" in the footnotemark's page number and "31" is the footnotetext page number.
Please, keep in mind that the redefinition of the `\footenote` command is intended to be temporary.

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Just a try: see [Footnote appears on next page. Why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225182/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob I'm not able to reproduce the problem on a MWE and the files I'm working on are copyrighted material. I'll provide anyway a minimal working code.

Comment: You could use dummy text manually or with `lipsum` or `blindtext`. https://texblog.org/2011/02/26/generating-dummy-textblindtext-with-latex-for-testing/. It is importent to see your problem. Pleace try to reprocude your problem with manimial and not copyrighted text

Comment: Is it a standard `\footnote` or something like `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`?

Comment: @egreg Always standard `\footnote`. I hoped in your help 'cause you fixed a similar issue in the past: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365954/33634 ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure how a standard footnote can get detached from its marker. Something more detailed is needed.

Comment: @egreg. It doesn't matter for my purposes. Once I detect the problem I can easily fix it. In this specific case the problem is caused by a `\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}` string. But I would find a way to automatically detect this problems (e.g. with a script).

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Using `\afterpage` in a production environment is not recommended.

Comment: @egreg I really thank you for you help but my problem is not the `\afterpage` package (that I use carefully). I encountered this kind of problem with the footnotes layout in different contexts. I'm not finding a way to avoid them but to detect them. Please let's stay on the topic.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi This *is* on topic. About the (wrong) problem: the footnotes are added during the output routine and their text and formatting has already been done.

Comment: @egreg I've already fixed it. I'm searching for a way to detect this kind of problems in the future.

Comment: I've never had LaTeX put the footnote mark on a different page from the footnote. @egreg What's the problem with `\afterpage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works for my purposes:

I'll compile with:

```
latex '\AtBeginDocument{\newcounter{MyFootnote} \let\MyOldFootnot  \footnote \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\stepcounter{MyFootnote}\label{FootnoteMark\arabic{MyFootnote}}\MyOldFootnote{\label{FootnoteText\arabic{MyFootnote}}#1}}} \input{Footnotes.tex}'
```

And I'll get in the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{FootnoteMark1}{{5}{1}}
\newlabel{FootnoteText1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{FootnoteMark2}{{5}{2}}
\newlabel{FootnoteText2}{{2}{2}}
\newlabel{FootnoteMark3}{{5}{3}}
\newlabel{FootnoteText3}{{3}{3}}
```

so I can compare  (with a script) the page numbers of footnotemark and footenotetext.

I know it is not the most beautiful solution but it works for me.

Comment: You are right that it would take \label or at least \protected@write\@auxout to get the correct page numbers.