# Passing \AtBeginDocument{...} to latexmk

Tags: latexmk

I need to compile with this string (this question is related to [this other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/381623/33634)):

```
latex '\AtBeginDocument{\newcounter{MyFootnote} \let\MyOldFootnote\footnote \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\stepcounter{MyFootnote}\label{FootnoteMark\arabic{MyFootnote}}\MyOldFootnote{\label{FootnoteText\arabic{MyFootnote}}#1}}} \input{myfile.tex}'
```

(I'm sorry but I don't know hot to diplay it in a more readeble way...)

But it would be better if I could use latexmk instead. I tried:

```
latexmk -latex="\AtBeginDocument{\newcounter{MyFootnote} \let\MyOldFootnote\footnote \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\stepcounter{MyFootnote}\label{FootnoteMark\arabic{MyFootnote}}\MyOldFootnote{\label{FootnoteText\arabic{MyFootnote}}#1}}}" myfile.tex
```

but it doesn't work.

Here's a MWE:

```
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}

\section{Section}

Some dummy text.\footnote{Some dummy text.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably need to quote more characters but wouldn't it be easier to just use latexmk on a file `myfile.abc` where `myfile.abc`  is `\AtBeginDocument{\newcounter{MyFootnote} \let\MyOldFootnote\footnote \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\stepcounter{MyFootnote}\label{FootnoteMark\arabic{MyFootnote}}\MyOldFootnote{\label{FootnoteText\arabic{MyFootnote}}#1}}}\input{myfile.tex}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried `latexmk myfile.abc` as you suggested... but it does not work.

Comment: Why not make a latexmkrc file that redefines the $latex command?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Honestly I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Please read the latexmk documentation. Run `texdoc latemk` for TeX Live.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thank you. I learned a lot reading the latexmk documentation. I think that for my purposes it is better to run the latex command 2 times as I know that this will generate the correct aux file. I suppose that latexmk in this case is a bit overkill (see the related post).