# Footnote in align environment on the same page

Tags: align, footnotes, page

A follow-up question about [Footnote in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode). When using `\footnotemark` within the `align` environment at the end of the page, the footnote appears on the next page. Here's a minimal example. How do I get the footnote to appear on the same page as the footnote mark?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Title.
\vspace{19cm}
\begin{align}
  1.\footnotemark
\end{align}
\footnotetext{Footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is not enough space on the page to display both the align environment and the footnote on one page. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225171/134144

Comment: You could force both the equation and the footnote to the next page with the needspace package.

Answer (score 2):

this is cheating.  it is a hack.  it assumes that this footnote will not be
the first in the document.

this has the effect of moving both the display and the footnote to the next page.

(irrelevant, but it's not a good idea to use `align` for a one-line display.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Title.
\vspace{19cm}
\footnotetext{Footnote.}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\begin{align}
  1.\footnotemark
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code, first page]
[image: output of example code, second page]